# How to implement a custom security extension on a Spring security/OAuth2 based app?

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am currently integrating Spring security and its OAuth 2.0 implementation in two applications. At the beginning, the overall architecture was as follow :

1. **Application A** is a front-end app. It lives on its own and implements
   the business logic related to its own domain. It has its own authentication mechanism (based on a local users table).

   It also has a feature called **super-password** which allows a *local user* to be promoted as Application A's admin if this user is listed in a local **adminList** table and if he/she provides the right admin password. This feature is a **sudo-like feature** and allows the user to **emulate** another **user's context** (mostly for helpdesk-related tasks).
2. **Application B** is an independent app based on Spring Security and uses Spring's OAuth 2.0 implementation. We use it as a central authentication point for our other front-end apps.

We then managed to move all the **authentication hassle** from Application A to Application B. So now, the local user table in Application A is not needed anymore, everything related to user authentication were moved to Application B.

The only thing remaining is the **super-password feature** :
Would it be possible to move this feature (as an extension) to Application B (Auth responsible) and still have Application B as a **generic authentication server** for all the other apps ?

If yes then, how can it be achieved using Spring security/OAuth 2 mechanism ?

Or, would it be better, since it's an Application A-related feature, if we leave it implemented only on Application A ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.